# Store Cached image path in Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, universal-image-loader

I can  download  images  from  the  web  and  save  them  to  Cache,  now  I  need  to  store  their  path  in  SQLite  Database.  Any  help  please  !!  thanx  in  advance.  Below  is  my  code  Snippet  with   help  from  http://www.androidhive.info:

```
//Saving  Cached  Images  to  File  E_Meges
package com.img.see;

import java.io.File;

import android.content.Context;

public class Cache2Fyle {

     private File kacheDirectory;

        public Cache2Fyle(Context context){

            //Find the dir to save cached images
            if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))

  kacheDirectory= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"E_Megez");

 else
                kacheDirectory=context.getCacheDir();

 if(!kacheDirectory.exists())

 kacheDirectory.mkdirs();

 }

 public File getFile(String url){

  String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

            File fyl = new File(kacheDirectory, filename);

            return fyl;

        }

        public void clear(){

  File[] files=kacheDirectory.listFiles();

            if(files==null)

                return;

            for(File fyl:files)

                fyl.delete();
        }

}
```

//Main  Class  to  Display

```
package com.img.see;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ImageView;


public class SampleCaching extends Activity {

  @Override

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);


          int loader = R.drawable.loader;


        // Imageview to show

  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);


        // Url for  Image  from  web        
   String image_url = "http://muk.akatsuki.info/photos/Image1.jpg";

  ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());


     imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);

 }
}
```

//Database  table

```
    String img = "CREATE TABLE photos ( _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Name TEXT, Image TEXT)";
```